# python mirroring string using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, mirroring, mirror

I want to write a function mirror() that takes a string and returns its mirror image but only if the mirror image can be represented using letters in the alphabet.

Example:

```
>>> mirror('vow')
'wov'
>>> mirror('wood')
'boow'
>>> mirror('bed')
'INVALID'
```

The mirror image of string bed cannot be represented as a string because the mirror image of e is not a valid character.

I have written:

```
def mirror(str):
   mir={'b':'d','d':'b','o':'o','p':'q','q':'p','v':'v','w':'w','x':'x'}
   for char in str:
      while char in mir:
         return str[::-1]
   return 'INVALID'
```

I can't figure out how to replace the string characters with the dictionary equivalents and how to iterate over the entire string.

Comment: It is literally the same question.

Comment: That's likely to be some kind of homework

Comment: I think that is pretty obvious, but I didn't want to be the guy that says "this looks like homework" because once someone says that, the downvotes rain in.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this question's poor quality here is a working solution:

```
def mirror(s):
    xs = {
        "b": "d", "d": "b", "o": "o", "p": "q",
        "q": "p", "v": "v", "w": "w", "x": "x"
    }

    if all([c in xs for c in s]):
        return "".join([xs[c] for c in s])

    return "INVALID"


print mirror("vow")
print mirror("wood")
print mirror("bed")
```

**Example:**

```
$ python -i foo.py
vow
woob
INVALID
>>>
```

*Hopefully* you can learn something from this.